# TimePicker from Extended Wpf Toolkit don't tab properly with tabIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, timepicker

I use a TimePicker control from the latest Extended Wpf Toolkit build.
I setted a tabindex in the XAML. My problem is thaht the cursor never go on this contrôl :(

**Here is my xaml piece :**

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="147*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="162*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="191*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Width="35"/>
  <DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker_Date" TabIndex="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Padding="2,1" Margin="0,3" Width="149" />
  <xctk:TimePicker Grid.Column="2" x:Name="TimePicker_Heure" TabIndex="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Margin="102,4,10,4"/>
  <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Heure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,1,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Width="44"/>
</Grid>
```

Have you an idea please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: More information is needed, what are the other controls with tabindexes? What are their respective indexes? What container are they inside? Are your indexes being locally scoped to a given container?

Comment: Ok, so what behaviour are you observing? Where is the focus going when you do tab? Have you tried changing the tab indexes to 1 and 2 as I can only see a 3 and 4 in your XAML.

Comment: I have asked this question to the Extended WPF Toolkit and they told me it was a fixe issue in the 2.0 ! But...I don't know when the 2.0 will be out. Anyone know if there is a way to fix it ?

Comment: if the toolkit is open source then just look at the changeset between the version before 2.0 (if the source for that is online) and your answer will likely be there :)